# Unclassifiable statement at a/SIN(A)=b/SIN(B)=g/SIN(G)

Tags: fortran

```
PROGRAM
IMPLICIT NONE
REAL:: A , B , G
PRINT*,'DWSTE THN a'
READ*,a
PRINT*,'DWSTE THN b'
READ*,b
PRINT*,'DWSTE THN G'
READ*,G
g = SQRT( a**2 + b**2 -2*a*b*COS(G)
PRINT*,g
a/SIN(A)=b/SIN(B)=g/SIN(G)
PRINT A,B
END
```

the compilation fails with

```
EXIT CODE 1
UNCLASSIFIABLE STATEMENT AT
a/SIN(A)=b/SIN(B)=g/SIN(G)
```

Comment: Please format your code.  There are a number of error with it.  `a/sin(a) = b/sin(b) = g/sin(g)` isn't valid Fortran.

Comment: Welcome please supply the details. Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide the details about the file name, compiler and how you compile. And please no shouting (i.e use all capitals in title and text, in the code it is OK as this is not shouting but the Fortran code form).

Comment: Please do **not** write in ALL CAPS, turn off your Caps lock.

Comment: Next to the various problems, be advised that Fortran is **case-insensitive**, this means that `g` and `G` are actually the same numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The reported problem is here

```
a/SIN(A)=b/SIN(B)=g/SIN(G)
```

and the message really means that the compiler does not understand what does it mean. Neither do I, it certainly is not legal Fortran syntax and I do not know what you are trying to do there.

You are also missing a parenthesis in

```
SQRT( a**2 + b**2 -2*a*b*COS(G)
```

Comment: I want to calculate the angles A,b from law of sines

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that Fortran is a programing language and cannot be confused with mathematical interpreters such as Maple or Mathematica, In such languages, it could be possible that a statement such as

```
a/SIN(A)=b/SIN(B)=g/SIN(G)
```

would automatically solve all unknowns. In Fortran, however, you actually have to tell Fortran how to solve this problem. Since you know `g` and `G` as well as `a`, so you can get

```
A=ASIN(SIN(G)*a/g)
```

Also, for your information: Fortran is not case sensitive. So the variables `g` and `G` are the same.